# How to quantify spatial distribution of signal in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, signal-processing, spatial

Let's assume I have 2 matrices, which are representing a signalling with 1 and 0 in a 2D space.

```
A = [1,1,0,0;1,1,0,0;1,1,0,0];
A =

 1     1     0     0
 1     1     0     0
 1     1     0     0

B = [1,0,1,1;1,0,0,1;1,0,0,0];
B =
 1     0     1     1
 1     0     0     1
 1     0     0     0
```

Matrix A seems to cluster the signal, while matrix B is more random distributed. My goal is to identify noise with this approach in images, which should be much less structured than real signal.

Is there `regionprops` function which can do that? Any other suggestions?

My approach so far:

- Measure distances between the positive patches (get average)
- Use `bwareafilt` to detect the biggest patch.

Comment: What about [histograms](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html#buhzm_z-7)?

Comment: How would this enable to describe a SPATIAL distribution?

Comment: You could also find the "range" of the variogram associated with your 2d matrix. A big range will indicate a strong spatial autocorrelation.

Comment: Could you provide us with some more details?

Answer (score 0):

I used a black and white image in which blackish was text and blackish was noise.
I just bruteforced for pixel wise checking in the code. **Idea is:**

> If any non-white pixel is surrounded by 5 or more whitish(thr value>230) pixel, consider it noise and make it white.

```
for k=1:num_you_like 
c=0; img_inp=img_final;

for i=2:(length(img_inp(:,1))-1)
    for j=2:(length(img_inp(1,:))-1)
if(img_final(i,j)<255)
    if (img_inp(i-1,j)>230)
        c=c+1;
    end
    if (img_inp(i+1,j)>230)
        c=c+1;
    end
    if (img_inp(i,j-1)>230)
        c=c+1;
    end
    if (img_inp(i,j+1)>230)
        c=c+1;
    end
    if (img_inp(i-1,j-1)>230)
        c=c+1;
    end
    if (img_inp(i-1,j+1)>230)
        c=c+1;
    end
    if (img_inp(i+1,j-1)>230)
        c=c+1;
    end
    if (img_inp(i+1,j+1)>230)
        c=c+1;
    end
    if c>5
      img_final(i,j)=255;
    end
    c=0;
end
end
end
```

[image: original][image: for num_you_like=1]

For different threshold of whitish(here i took 230) and different iterations, you can try and see the change. Though this was just a observation in my image and i felt like your matrix is cluster of black with some random whites...

> It would be easier to answer i we knew what the images are like, maybe add in your question, and comment on usefulness of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a naive approach but what about considering multiplying binary matrice with flipped version of it:

```
d = ( A .* flipud(fliplr(A)) ) / numel(A);
```

If `1` and `0` are randomly distributed, there are as many chances that you will have `1x1` or `1x0`. If data are more clustered it is more likely that `1x0` will be more prevalent. So randomly distributed data will have `d` close to 0.5

Flipping may not work in all cases, for instance:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

but you can do `circshift` for different lags ... if all lags are in average close to 0.5 it is likely that `1` and `0` are randomely distributed.

You question makes me think of evaluating the entropy of your binary data and here is similar question on stackexchange that I come through and that may provide more ideas :

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17109/measuring-entropy-information-patterns-of-a-2d-binary-matrix